# Java - Method not taking in consideration of the value given of the instance

Tags: java

```
public class Square {
    int length ;

    Rectangle(length) {
    }
    public double perimeter() {
        return 4 * length;
    }

    public double area() {
        return  length * length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle c = new Rectangle(14);
        System.out.println(c.area());
        System.out.println(c.perimeter());
    }
}
```

I get values of 0.0 and 0.0. How can I make it to consider the value given for `Rectangle c (14)` ?

What am I missing?

Comment: Your constructor is empty. You're not setting `radius` anywhere in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define a variable in your class: `int radius;` (below `int rayon`) and then in the constructor you have to put the following line: `this.radius = radius;` where `this` refers to the radius declared in the class that you will initialize it with the value passed to the constructor (14 in your case). Also, I don't see you using the `rayon` variable somewhere, so you can delete it. The constructor will be:

```
Cercle(int radius) {
   this.radius = radius;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! (rayon was a mistake lost in translation, everything was rayon or everything SHOULD be radius)

Answer (score 2):

You never set the radius in your constructor, so it is 0 by default. You then proceed to multiply the other values by the radius, which is still 0.